# What does an angle bracket pair (<>) do in VHDL?

Tags: fpga, vhdl

I am looking at some VHDL code and the following lines are present:

```
type obj_code_t is array(integer range <>) of std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
```

and

```
OBJ_CODE : obj_code_t;
```

What does the `<>` signify?

Comment: IEEE Std 1076-2008 5.3.2 Array types, 5.3.2.1 "... The values of the left and right bounds of each index range are not defined, but shall belong to the corresponding index subtype; similarly, the direction of each index range is not defined. The symbol <> (called a *box*) in an index subtype definition stands for an undefined range (different objects of the type need not have the same bounds and direction)."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The  "array(integer range <>)" syntax is used to declare an array with an unconstrained length.

See [this page](http://vhdl.renerta.com/mobile/source/vhd00054.htm) for detailed info on VHDL ranges.  Some snippets from the page are shown below.

[image: range def]

An example of an unconstrained array definition:

[image: unconstrained range]

Comment: Changed in -2008 to unbounded array definition where the element subtype can be unconstrained as well as the array index inheriting subtype from the index type. See IEEE Std 1076-2008 5.3.2 Array types, 5.3.2.1.